# Database not adding while having a social login in MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a `social media login` option in my login page with the help of `hybrid auth` plugin.

When the user clicks on login as facebook or any other social media plugin, I'm getting the logged in page or success page in which I'm trying to fetch data of the user and adding it to my own database in `MySql`, but it is not adding up. Following is my code:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../nits-admin/version.php');

//database connection  at top and also once only 

global $link;
$server   = 'localhost';
$user     = 'root';
$password = '';
$db       = 'nits_editor';

$link = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

if (!$link) {
    die("Connection Failed!:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}


session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../nits-db/db.php');

if (isset($_POST["user_email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $useremail = $_POST["user_email"];
    $password  = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nits_user WHERE user_email ='$useremail' AND user_password ='$password'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $user_id = $row["user_id"];
        }
        $_SESSION["user_id"]    = $user_id;
        $_SESSION["loggedin"]   = ture;
        $_SESSION["user_email"] = $useremail;
        $_SESSION["password"]   = $password;
        $_SESSION["user_name"]  = $row["user_name"];
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'Information incorrect';
    }
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST["provider"])) {
    //the selected provider
    $provider_name = $_REQUEST["provider"];
    try {
        // inlcude HybridAuth library
        // change the following paths if necessary
        $config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/hybridauth/config.php';
        require_once("hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php");

        // initialize Hybrid_Auth class with the config file
        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

        // try to authenticate with the selected provider
        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider_name);

        // then grab the user profile
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    }

    // something went wrong?
    catch (Exception $e) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

    /*
     * get the user data from database by provider name and provider user id
     **/
    function get_user_by_provider_and_id($provider_name, $provider_user_id, $link)
    {
        $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM nits_user WHERE hybridauth_provider_name = '$provider_name' AND hybridauth_provider_uid = '$provider_user_id'";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $qry1);

        return mysqli_fetch_object($result1);


    }



    // check if the current user already have authenticated using this provider before
    $user_exist = get_user_by_provider_and_id($provider_name, $user_profile->identifier, $link);

    // if the used didn't authenticate using the selected provider before
    // we create a new entry on database.users for him
    if (!$user_exist) {



        function create_new_hybridauth_user($email, $first_name, $last_name, $provider_name, $provider_user_id, $link)
        {
            // let generate a random password for the user
            $password = md5(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnoABCDEFGHIJ"));

            $qry2 = ("INSERT INTO nits_user
                        (
                            user_email,
                            user_password,
                            user_firstname,
                            user_lastname,
                            hybridauth_provider_name,
                            hybridauth_provider_uid,
                            user_createdate
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                            '$email',
                            '$password',
                            '$first_name',
                            '$last_name',
                            $provider_name,
                            $provider_user_id,
                            NOW()
                        );");


            $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $qry2);



            //$last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);


            return $email;
        }


        $val = create_new_hybridauth_user($user_profile->email, $user_profile->firstName, $user_profile->lastName, $provider_name, $user_profile->identifier, $link);


        if ($val) {

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;



            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }


    } else {

        // set the user as connected and redirect him

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user_profile->email;



        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        header("Location: login.php");

    }
}




?>
```

I'm not getting Database connection error, I mean connection is appropriate, as while logging in with username and password it matches with the database and redirects the defined page.
Don't be concern with the password, I'll be using `password_hash()`. 
Please help me out!!!
Thanks

Comment: $provider_name is without quotes.  Also, password_hash is the least of my concerns with your code. You should really use prepared statements and MySQL PDO to avoid MySQL injection.

Comment: First check whether you are able to enter `create_new_hybridauth_user` function or not ?

Comment: Change `mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {` TO `mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` because it Required Specifies a result set identifier returned by mysqli_query() not your sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to debug your code as below

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["provider"])) {
    //the selected provider
    $provider_name = $_REQUEST["provider"];
    try {
        // inlcude HybridAuth library
        // change the following paths if necessary
        $config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/hybridauth/config.php';
        require_once("hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php");

        // initialize Hybrid_Auth class with the config file
        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

        // try to authenticate with the selected provider
        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider_name);

        // then grab the user profile
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    }

    // something went wrong?
    catch (Exception $e) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

    /*
     * get the user data from database by provider name and provider user id
     * */

    function get_user_by_provider_and_id($provider_name, $provider_user_id, $link) {
        $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM nits_user WHERE hybridauth_provider_name = '".$provider_name."' AND hybridauth_provider_uid = '".$provider_user_id."'";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $qry1);

        return mysqli_fetch_object($result1);
    }

    // check if the current user already have authenticated using this provider before
    $user_exist = get_user_by_provider_and_id($provider_name, $user_profile->identifier, $link);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_exist);
    // if the used didn't authenticate using the selected provider before
    // we create a new entry on database.users for him
    if (!$user_exist) {



        function create_new_hybridauth_user($email, $first_name, $last_name, $provider_name, $provider_user_id, $link) {
            // let generate a random password for the user
            $password = md5(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnoABCDEFGHIJ"));

            $qry2 = ("INSERT INTO nits_user
                        (
                            user_email,
                            user_password,
                            user_firstname,
                            user_lastname,
                            hybridauth_provider_name,
                            hybridauth_provider_uid,
                            user_createdate
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                            '".$email."',
                            '".$password."',
                            '".$first_name."',
                            '".$last_name."',
                            '".$provider_name."',
                            '".$provider_user_id."',
                            NOW()
                        );");


            $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $qry2)or die(mysqli_error($link));


            $last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            echo 'lastinsertid:'.$last_insert_id;

            return $email;
        }

        $val = create_new_hybridauth_user($user_profile->email, $user_profile->firstName, $user_profile->lastName, $provider_name, $user_profile->identifier, $link);


        if ($val) {
            echo 'email:'.$val;
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;



            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'userexist:';
        // set the user as connected and redirect him

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user_profile->email;



        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
```